# Counting number of non-singular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

How many non-singular matrices of order 3x3 we can form in which 4 entries are 1 and other entries are zero..
Any short​trick??

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: 100 010 001 fixing this and adding one 1 at any one of the zero's place det remains non zero E.g 101 010 001 and so on.. also matrices of the form 110 100 001 , 100 011 010... So Atleast 8 such we can have..

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Specifically, 
[Matrices](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5023/290196).

Comment: Think about determinants. You know that there can't be any zero row or column, so you can restrict your options for the first 3 ones you place. The fourth one can then go anywhere you want.

Comment: Since permuting rows doesn't change being singular vs. non-singular, I would start by breaking down cases in which the rows are ordered by the number of ones in each.  With only four entries $1$, there are not  a huge number of possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

*Hints.*

- If the matrix is nonsingular, it must possess a circulant diagonal/anti-diagonal $\{a_{i\sigma(i)}:i=1,2,3,\ \sigma\in S_3\}$ of ones. How many such diagonals/anti-diagonals are there?
- Having fixed the diagonal of ones, how many ways are there to put the remaining one?

Answer (score 1):

We need at least one triple of $1$s appearing in ${\rm det}(A)$. If such a  triple has been chosen, e.g., the diagonal of $A$, then the fourth $1$ cannot create a second such triple. Since there are six such triples in all, and for each of them there are six spots to place the last $1$  there are $36$ regular matrices of this kind.